# Need one display function for dyanamic MULTIDIMENSION ARRAY display IN PHP

Tags: php, soap

QS1. The results mention below is from one  array  ( got from WEBSERVICE CALL using SOAP). i have some confusion regarding accessing elements from the array. As seen from the results, sometime results comes as an ARRAY (in second result) where as sometimes results comes without array index (first results). SO how can I use the best method  for displaying elements  like array["AirportCode"] for getting accurate results and display output TO user.

```
*********************
RESULTS SET-1
********************

  Array
    (
    [SegmentIndicator] => 1
    [Airline] => Array
    (
    [AirlineCode] => SG
    [AirlineName] => SpiceJet
    [AirLineRemarks] => SG Star Coupon
    )

    [FlightNumber] => 894
    [FareClass] => K
    [Origin] => Array
    (
    [AirportCode] => GAU
    [AirportName] => Borjhar
    [Terminal] =>
    [CityCode] => GAU
    [CityName] => Guwahati
    [CountryCode] => IN
    [CountryName] => India
    )

    [Destination] => Array
    (
    [AirportCode] => DEL
    [AirportName] => Indira Gandhi Airport
    [Terminal] => 1C
    [CityCode] => DEL
    [CityName] => Delhi
    [CountryCode] => IN
    [CountryName] => India
    )

    [DepTIme] => 2014-12-26T11:05:00
    [ArrTime] => 2014-12-26T14:00:00
    [ETicketEligible] => 1
    [Duration] => 02:55
    [Stop] => 0
    [Craft] => 738
    [Status] => Confirmed
    [OperatingCarrier] => SG
    )
*****************************************
RESULTS SET-2
****************************************
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[SegmentIndicator] => 1
[Airline] => Array
(
[AirlineCode] => AI
[AirlineName] => Air India
[AirLineRemarks] => This JetAirways series are operated by JetLite
)

[FlightNumber] => 401
[FareClass] => Y
[Origin] => Array
(
[AirportCode] => DEL
[AirportName] => Indira Gandhi Airport
[Terminal] => 3
[CityCode] => DEL
[CityName] => Delhi
[CountryCode] => IN
[CountryName] => India
)

[Destination] => Array
(
[AirportCode] => CCU
[AirportName] => Calcutta
[Terminal] => 2
[CityCode] => CCU
[CityName] => Kolkata
[CountryCode] => IN
[CountryName] => India
)

[DepTIme] => 2014-12-31T07:00:00
[ArrTime] => 2014-12-31T09:05:00
[ETicketEligible] => 1
[Duration] => 00:00
[Stop] => 0
[Craft] => 321
[Status] => Confirmed
[OperatingCarrier] => AI
)

[1] => Array
(
[SegmentIndicator] => 1
[Airline] => Array
(
[AirlineCode] => 9W
[AirlineName] => Jet Airways
[AirLineRemarks] => This JetAirways series are operated by JetLite
)

[FlightNumber] => 2363
[FareClass] => H
[Origin] => Array
(
[AirportCode] => CCU
[AirportName] => Calcutta
[Terminal] =>
[CityCode] => CCU
[CityName] => Kolkata
[CountryCode] => IN
[CountryName] => India
)

[Destination] => Array
(
[AirportCode] => GAU
[AirportName] => Borjhar
[Terminal] =>
[CityCode] => GAU
[CityName] => Guwahati
[CountryCode] => IN
[CountryName] => India
)

[DepTIme] => 2014-12-31T10:45:00
[ArrTime] => 2014-12-31T11:55:00
[ETicketEligible] => 1
[Duration] => 00:00
[Stop] => 0
[Craft] => 738
[Status] => Confirmed
[OperatingCarrier] => 9W
)
```

Comment: Case 1: print myarray['AirportCode']; Case 2: myarray[0]['AirportCode']; You can do a for each, the structure is the same, one time with 1 element (Case1), one time with more elements (case2)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. if myarray contains index [0] to [n] elements. then what to do for printing elements? And how to dynamically determine case1 and case2 as I am using the above results in loop.

Comment: for each :) or a for loop, etc... you can loop trough multiple array ^_^ Example: for ($i = 0; $i < count(myArray); $i++){//myArraySearch}

Comment: but incase of "results set 1" this count(myArray) may not be appropriate as I have to test results inside another primary loop and need to determine whether case1 or case2 (according to your first reply)

Comment: You haven't understand me, i'll write an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'll write a loop that will work both case. I'll show only one var -> AirportCode <-

first, i'll have a var called myArray with the array.

```
$myArray = .... // Do what you need to populate it.
```

Now let's make a cicle.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++){
 if(isset($myArray[$i]['AirportCode'])){
  print  $myArray[$i]['AirportCode'];
}
}
```

You need however to test this code.

Comment: I need to clear another confusion suppose $myArray[$i]['AirportCode']['index1']['index2']...! Is it possible to check using only isset($myArray[$i]) instead of the entire key index since I have lot of key index after AirportCode

Comment: It depends. The field AirportCode (Example) is always setted?

Comment: Nothing dude, before using an isset of the global array you need to know what is always setted :)